# Change Notification with Oracle Dependency in C#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I'm trying to get oracle database change notification in c#. I found 
[this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featChange.htm#BABDGFBH) about how to get these notifications. I've also created simple win form application for catching notifications

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetUpNotification();
    }

    private void SetUpNotification()
    {
        var login = "DATA SOURCE=XE;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=USR;PASSWORD=PWD";

        OracleConnection conn = null;
        OracleDependency dep = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(login);

            var cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from customer_details", conn);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.AddRowid = true;
            dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
            cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, e.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    void dep_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(eventArgs.Details.ToString(), "Database changed");
    }
}
```

Login string and OracleCommand cmd are 100% fine. I tried also to change database programmatically, it changed data in database, but didn't fired OnChange event.

I also granted notifications tu USR user

```
grant change notification to USR
```

and job_queue_processes are greater than zero.

Can be a problem in a fact, that I am using **Express edition** of oracle database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the solution. Problem wasn't in edition of Oracle database, but in the version. Version of Oracle server was **11.2.0.2.0** and version of client was **11.2.0.3.0** and this little difference was causing the problem.

So for the future, alway check the versions of client and server, when encountering similar problem.

Comment: So, are you saying that for this feature to work, the database and client versions have to match exactly?  What did you do to solve the problem?  Did you downgrade your client?

Comment: I have matching 11.2.0.2.0 versions on Server and Client and I can't get this to work.  I see the registration of the Change Notification in DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS, but after the commit on the monitored table the registration disappears and my app does not receive the notification.

Comment: Sorry I won't help you. We have upgraded to 11.2.0.3.0 and I don't remember now if it worked also with 11.2.0.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Also you missed `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` in your code. Without executing of command this code will not work regardless of the version of the database.

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from new_place", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.AddRowid = true;
var dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```