# Oracledependency event is not firing

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have some problems using OracleDependency.

I've read docs on msdn and oracle and copy some code to try it.

However this is not working, the event on_my_event doesn't fire when the insert is done.

Does anyone know why ?

My user has CHANGE NOTIFICATION rights on the database. Oracle Server is 11.2.0.3.0.

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string connection_string = "Data Source=My_srv;User Id=My_usr;Password=My_pwd;";
    OracleConnection connection = null;
    OracleDependency dependency = null;
    OracleCommand my_select = null;
    OracleCommand my_insert = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TB_insert_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_insert.Text == "Name of your insert")
            TB_insert.Clear();
    }

    private void insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new OracleConnection(connection_string);
        my_insert = connection.CreateCommand();
        my_insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USR_DEV_TRUNK.WPARAM (wpa_codeparam) VALUES ('" + TB_insert.Text + "')";
        connection.Open();
        my_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

    private void Set_dep(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleDependency.Port = 3048;
        connection = new OracleConnection(connection_string);
        connection.Open();
        my_select = connection.CreateCommand();
        my_select.CommandText = "SELECT wpa_codeparam FROM USR_DEV_TRUNK.WPARAM";
        dependency = new OracleDependency();
        dependency.AddCommandDependency(my_select);
        my_select.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
        my_select.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(on_my_event);
        TB_dependency.Text = "The dependency is set, do your insert to see if it works";
        connection.Close();
    }

    public void on_my_event(object obj, OracleNotificationEventArgs arg)
    {
        TB_dependency.Text = "Yay ! It worked !";
    }
  }
}
```

I have two buttons :

One to set my dependency (function (on click) : Set_dep)

One to do my insert (function (on click) : insert)

And i have two textboxs :

One to get my insert (name : TB_insert)

One to show the dependency state (name : TB_dependency)

Comment: A while ago, @LadislavM found it important that [server and client version exactly match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932968/change-notification-with-oracle-dependency-in-c-sharp). Did you check that? 11.2.0.3.0 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure packets on port 3048 are not getting blocked by a firewall?

Also, once your dependency has been set, can you see it by querying the USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS / DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS views?

Comment: This should have been a comment.