# Persistent web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, service

I am new to software architecture but not to programming. I have been tasked with making a service that checks a database and if a new row has been added email selected people. The data also needs to be accessible from the intranet (web api?). I am not sure what technology to use for this. I have been solely a desktop and asp.net developer. Is there a technology in the c# windows realm that can do this?

Comment: What kind of database? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c) which deals with a similar case on an SQL server

Comment: @Bradley Moorfield Its an Oracle DB

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm

Comment: Thanks! now should I be using wcf? Or should I make a windows service and a webapi?

Comment: You should be able to use just about anything, [here's a winforms example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932968/change-notification-with-oracle-dependency-in-c-sharp)